# MySQL RIGHT JOIN SUM() from Table B to Info on Table A

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically I have a load of product information on Table A. This include the product_id which is the common id over both tables. On Table B I have a list of votes which include product_id, username, thevote(could be +1 or -1).

So basically I want to have a table of 'Table A' with a additional column containing the SUM of all the votes for that product_ID. I am sure there is an easy way to do this. Which i think is using 'right join'.

I still want it to list all the products in Table A regardless if they have a single +1 or -1 vote.

Many thanks in advance peoples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `group by` statement and `left join` like:

```
select productName, sum(vote) as productVoteSum
from `products` p
left join `products_votes` pv on p.id = pv.productId
where productName like '%chocolat%'
group by p.id
order by productName;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. How do I add a 'WHERE' and 'SORTBY' to this state?

Comment: Just what I was looking for would give +2 if it was possible!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a LEFT JOIN (that goes through all the information on tableA and puts the SUM in the ones that have the matching product_id on tableB), then you add the SUM(b.thevote) and group by the remaining columns

```sql
SELECT a.product_id,a.productName,SUM(b.thevote)
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
GROUP BY a.product_id, a.productName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*, SUM(b.votes) FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.prouct_id=b.product_id
GROUP BY a.product_id
```